# Table is mutating. Trigger may not see it (Even on different tables)

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have two tables: `Group` and `Schedule`.
The `Group` table consists of columns: Group_Name, No_of_member.
The `Schedule` table consists of column: Group_Name, Schedule_Date.
A group can have many schedules.

I'm trying to create a trigger which deletes all corresponding records from the `Schedule` table when a particular record is deleted from the `Group` table. I have written a trigger as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER group_test
AFTER DELETE ON Group
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM Schedule WHERE Schedule.group_name = :old.group_name;
END;
```

But when I try to delete a record from the group table with command: `DELETE FROM Group WHERE group_name = 'AwesomeGroup';` , Oracle shows:

> `Table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.`
>
> `at line 2, error during execution of trigger 'group_test'`

This would make sense if I was trying to delete a record from the same table in which I've created the trigger (Group in this case), but I have the trigger on `Group` table and I'm trying to delete the records on `Schedule` table. So, why does oracle keep giving me this error?

Comment: Are you sure there is no second trigger which fails!? What is the full error message?

Comment: The Group table has 2 other triggers but I've disabled them both so only this trigger is enabled. The schedule table has no triggers.

Full error:
```Table "Group" is mutating, trigger/function may not see it,
at line 2,
error during execution of trigger 'group_test'```

Comment: Not a solution, but `GROUP` is a sql keyword. Avoid using it as a table name.

Comment: Check the foreign key definition on table `schedule` - assuming `group_name` is foreign key. For example, something like `on delete set null` or `on delete cascade` will cause a mutating table error - although in that case the "mutating table" is the `schedule` table, not the one on which the trigger is defined. In any case, look for things of this nature.

Comment: Make sure there is not a trigger on `Schedule` which attempts up update the `Group` table.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yes. That's true. I've changed it but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @mathguy Yeah. I've defined `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the `group_name` on the `Schedule` table. So, does this mean that I'm not allowed to define `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the `Schedule` table?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I'm completely sure that the `Schedule` does not have any triggers.

Comment: As @mathguy said, I had `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the `group_name` foreign key on the `Schedule` table. On removing this, the trigger worked without any error. But I don't understand how this was causing the error. Can I not have `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the `group_name` on `Schedule` table and this trigger side by side?

Comment: When you have a foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE (which would be the preferred way) then there is no need for the trigger. It is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have a `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause on table `Schedule` for the foreign key on column `group_name`.

So naturally, when you do the `DELETE` on table `Group`, Oracle automatically follows the foreign key and go delete the records in `Schedule`, which makes the table change.

This is what causes your trigger `group_test` to dysfunction. In fact, this trigger is redundant with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause. I agree with @WernfriedDomscheit, you **must** choose between one of the two solutions.